# Can I specify Excel's Data > Refresh All update order without using VBA?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Similar to the question [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4e3816f-e2a6-49f5-83eb-30bf8c65ef48/is-it-possible-to-order-refresh-connections-within-power-query-?forum=powerquery), I have a set 10+ queries where a few are external connections which get merged into a big table, which is then aggregated into a couple more tables, which are then summarized even further in some more tables.

In the link I gave, there is VBA code provided which I could use to make sure everything gets refreshed in the in the order I specify, which would be based on the query dependencies. However, for security reasons, I'd like to avoid having to save and share macro-enabled workbooks (`.xlsm`).

I know I could write all the queries to go back to the external data rather than doing it in steps, but I'm avoiding that because I actually use the intermediate steps themselves and making all the tables connect externally is much slower than just doing it once.

Is there some other option I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

I usually use numbered Query Groups.  Depending on your dependancies, you can probably group your queries into a handful of groups, e.g.

1. Extract
2. Transform
3. Output

Then the refresh process is simplified down to just right-clicking each Group and choosing Refresh.

You can also add a description to each Group to make this clearer.

BTW the numbers don't achieve anything themselves, but make the intent/use clearer.

Comment: Thank you! This is a useful tip. I'd still need to do at least four sets of refreshes in my particular case though.